# Qt Sqlite user access

Tags: sqlite, qt, access-control

I'm working with sqlite and qt. I understand that sqlite doesn't have native user access control and am fine with that, and have a plan for controlling access using my application - set up some user groups in a db and authenticate on the app side.

What I would like to know is if there is an easy way to stop my views on `QSqlRelationalTableModel` data from updating the database (i.e make the database readonly).

I am currently using an editstrategy of `OnFieldChange`, if I change it to `OnManualSubmit` for example (without implementing a submit call), will that prevent updates to the dB?

Is there a cleverer way of doing this? Like making the view readonly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create views, then they will be read-only since sqlite doesn't support updating views:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html

**EDIT**

Following-up on your comment, is the QSQLITE_OPEN_READONLY connection setting what you are looking for?
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but I want to be able to switch the ability to edit on and off depending on the user.

Comment: That will do it. I need to set that before opening the database, so turning it off means closing and reopening, but that's ok. Thanks!

Comment: @mike: this is probably due to Qt passing the parameter down to the C API where it is used on connection open: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_open_autoproxy.html